# How to map some source properties to a wrapped destination type using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

Suppose you have this source model:

```
public abstract class SourceModelBase {
}

public class SourceContact : SourceModelBase {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public KeyValuePair Pair { get; set; }
  public SourceAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class KeyValuePair { // Not derived from SourceModelBase.
  public string Key { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class SourceAddress : SourceModelBase {
  public string StreetName { get; set; }
  public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Now the destination model should be mapped 1:1 by default (subject to normal AutoMapper configuration), but each thing derived from `SourceModelBase` should be mapped to a wrapper class `class Wrap<T> { T Payload { get; set; } string Meta { get; set; } }`.

```
public abstract class DestinationModelBase {
}

public class DestinationContact : DestinationModelBase {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public KeyValuePair Pair { get; set; } // Not wrapped, base class not `SourceModelBase`.
  public Wrap<DestinationAddress> Address { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationAddress : DestinationModelBase {
  public string StreetName { get; set; }
  public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Since the contact class itself is derived from `SourceModelBase` it should be wrapped as well.

The result should have this structure:

```
Wrap<DestinationContact> Contact
  string Meta // Comes from the custom wrapper logic.
  DestinationContact Payload
    string FirstName
    string LastName
    KeyValuePair Pair
      string Key
      string Value
    Wrap<DestinationAddress> Address
      string Meta // Comes from the custom wrapper logic.
      DestinationAddress Payload
        string StreetName
        string StreetNumber
```

Obviously this wrapping should nest, illustrated by the fact that the mapped object itself is subject to it and so is its `Address` property.

For some reason all I keep finding are questions related to mapping from destination to source. I know I have to somehow use `ResolveUsing` and if the destination type is derived from `SourceModelBase`, somehow apply custom logic to provide the `Wrap<T>` value based on the value of the source property.

I don't know where to start at all, though. Especially when the source object itself is specified to be subject of the wrapping logic as well.

**What's the best, most AutoMapper-idiomatic way to wrap the nested objects if they meet a condition and at the same time wrap the original object as well if it meets the same condition?** I already have the mapper creation abstracted away so I can mold the original object automatically before passing it to the mapper, which may help with subjecting the original object to the resolver as well by doing `mapper.Map(new { Root = originalObject })` so the resolver sees the instance of the original object as if it was a value of a property of source object as well, not the source object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/694) on AutoMapper GitHub page, there is no direct way to do it.
But there is some workarounds. For example - reflection.
In this case you need to know wrapper type and implement converter for desired types. In this example it's `MapAndWrapConverter` from `TSource` to `Wrap<TDestination>`
`CreateWrapMap` method creates two bindings:
`SourceAddress -> Wrap<DestinationAddress>` and `SourceContact -> Wrap<DestinationContact>`  which allow you to map `SourceContant` to wrapped `DestinationContact`.

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceAddress, DestinationAddress>();
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceContact, DestinationContact>();

            cfg.CreateWrapMap(
                //func selecting types to wrap
                type => typeof(DestinationModelBase).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                        && !type.IsAbstract,
                typeof(Wrap<>),
                typeof(MapAndWrapConverter<,>));
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        //Using AutoFixture to create complex object
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var srcObj = fixture.Create<SourceContact>();

        var dstObj = mapper.Map<Wrap<DestinationContact>>(srcObj);
    }
}

public static class AutoMapperEx
{
    public static IMapperConfigurationExpression CreateWrapMap(
        this IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg,
        Func<Type, bool> needWrap, Type wrapperGenericType,
        Type converterGenericType)
    {
        var mapperConfiguration = 
            new MapperConfiguration((MapperConfigurationExpression)cfg);
        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

        foreach (var dstType in types.Where(needWrap))
        {
            var srcType = mapperConfiguration.GetAllTypeMaps()
                .Single(map => map.DestinationType == dstType).SourceType;
            var wrapperDstType = wrapperGenericType.MakeGenericType(dstType);
            var converterType = converterGenericType.MakeGenericType(srcType, dstType);
            cfg.CreateMap(srcType, wrapperDstType)
                .ConvertUsing(converterType);
        }
        return cfg;
    }
}
public class MapAndWrapConverter<TSource, TDestination> 
    : ITypeConverter<TSource, Wrap<TDestination>>
{
    public Wrap<TDestination> Convert(
        TSource source, Wrap<TDestination> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return new Wrap<TDestination>
        {
            Payload = context.Mapper.Map<TDestination>(source)
        };
    }
}
```

`CreateWrapMap` method is a little bit messy, especially the part with finding matching types. But it can be refined according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, this is an awesome starting point. I've played around with this for a bit now, confirmed that it correctly wraps objects in arrays, too... Seems to cover all my needs. Well done!

Comment: In 5.0.2, this should be made easier with the ForAllMaps method, that lets you go through all type maps without needing to call GetAllTypeMaps there. You can start with the existing type maps and look for things needing a wrap.

Comment: @JimmyBogard can you suggest an edit with this improvement? Because I'm facing problems like: mappings can't be modified during iterations and can't be collected because of deferred execution.